# Mounting network HD on startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, mount

First up I should note that I have no coding experience and am following guides.

I'm currently setting up a RaspPi with Raspbian as a Plex server.
Plex setup worked fine and I was able to mount the network hard drive (Seagate Central). Plex found files, good job.

However, on rebooting the Pi I lost the mount. After a bit of research it seems I need the disks UUID to mount on booting. For the life of me I cant find it.

Everything i read says to use command "blkid", which gives me the following;

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="59B0-FB97" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0007d388-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p5: LABEL="SETTINGS" UUID="85322d63-7f1f-4824-8ef3-5bc01a18c28d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0007d388-05"
/dev/mmcblk0p6: LABEL="boot" UUID="D702-6842" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0007d388-06"
/dev/mmcblk0p7: LABEL="root0" UUID="914a5b49-882d-406d-9ae7-d6e7d4b9e2c5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0007d388-07"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="0007d388" PTTYPE="dos"
```

command "df -T" gives me this; (other filesystems removed for space)

```
//'ipaddress'/boland cifs     3886415808 2625757376 1260658432  68% /media/HARDDRIVE
```

Just in case you need it, I mounted the drive using;

```
mkdir /media/HARDDRIVE

sudo mount -t cifs -o username=x,password=x //ipaddress/boland /media/HARDDRIVE
```

I'm on struggle street here, can i please get some help finding the UUID.
Alternatively if there is a way to mount on boot without the UUID that would be great.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Network mounts do not use UUIDs.

Comment: Any advice on how I would go about this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different solutions, one fstab solution and one systemd solution.

**fstab Solution**

You need to add your mounts to `/etc/fstab` to be mounted at startup.

For your example you need a line like

```
//ipaddress/boland  /media/HARDDRIVE  cifs  credentials=/etc/credentials,rw  0  0
```

in your `fstab`. Additionally you need a credentials file (`/etc/credentials` in my example):

```
username=x
password=x
domain=.
```

The credentials file should be readable only by root so change the rights with

```
chmod go-rwx /etc/credentials
```

**systemd Solution**

When the fstab solution above does not work you have to create mount units for systemd.

Create a file `media-HARDDRIVE.mount` in `/etc/systemd/system` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount smb share
Wants=network-online.service
After=network-online.service

[Mount]
What=//ipaddress/boland
Where=/media/HARDDRIVE
Type=cifs
Options=noauto,rw,credentials=/etc/cred
```

The credentials file can be the same as in solution 1.

Next create a file `media-HARDDRIVE.automount` in `/etc/systemd/system` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Automount smb share

[Automount]
Where=/media/HARDDRIVE

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

Next enable the mounting units with

```
sudo systemctl enable mnt-HARDDRIVE.automount
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now you can immediately mount the share with

```
sudo systemctl start mnt-HARDDRIVE.automount
```

After a reboot the share should now be mounted.

The file name of the mount unit must match the path to mount with escapes. To create the proper file name you can use the tool `systemd-escape media/HARDDRIVE` with the mount path name without leading `/`.

---

Explanation of the file `/etc/fstab`:

The file `/etc/fstab` contains the filesystems that will be mounted at boot time (there is a flag to disable this but this is a simple explanation). It basically has the following format:

```
what  where  type  options  freq  pass
```

The `what` indicates what will be mounted and the `where` where it will be mounted. The `type` indicates the fs-type and the options are th mounting options (which are specific to the fs-type). The `freq` is used for backup of ext2/ext3 filesystems (and should be set to 0 if you use any other fs). The last field `pass` is used to determine the order of the filesystem checks. For remote filesystems this should be set to 0 because no fs-check is needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73953/discussion-on-answer-by-uwe-plonus-mounting-network-hd-on-startup).

Comment: Thank Uwe Plonus. Got there by installing Raspbian directly and using your NOOBS solution on top. Legend!

Comment: For information: the systemd solution was named NOOBS solution before.